# Hash Value and back/next button

Tags: javascript

I have an url which contains a "hash": mySite.php#1

Client side: I get the hash value and do an Ajax call which add content to the DOM

When the user click 'next' or 'previous' button (browser), the page is not reload and so, the DOM stay the same even if the hash value change (the Ajax call is not done due to browser cache).

How can I force the browser to run my script in order to keep the DOM up to date (a hash value = a state in the DOM)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's what you need but have a go: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/